# Custom Pane In Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a custom static pane on the right side. so it shall be independent of zoom and scroll function in excel. please see the image for more. I tried the following. but no success.

I not sure whether the split-screen function in excel can help to achieve this.
Please note: I want to do it in page layout mode. as I was to set cell sizes in inch.
I tried the following.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").zoom = False
```

I have no idea to make it work, as I am new to VBA. I need a user interface something like in the picture below. so I can scroll on the left but static part on right. in the static part, I would be able to add custom controls like Combobox, command button, TextBox, etc. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You cannot make those using VBA. The closest thing to it would be a form, but it would not be docked like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

- VSTO Taskpane add-in:
  Custom task panes give you a way to create your own task pane and provide users with a familiar interface to access your solution's features. Custom task panes let you integrate your features into a familiar user interface. You can create a custom task pane quickly by using Visual Studio tools.

Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

- Office JS Taskpane add-in:
  You can create an Office Add-in by using the Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins or Visual Studio. The Yeoman generator creates a Node.js project that can be managed with Visual Studio Code or any other editor, whereas Visual Studio creates a Visual Studio solution. Select the tab for the one you'd like to use and then follow the instructions to create your add-in and test it locally.

Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: how does the node.js task pane run if your distributing the workbook to client? does it require a cloud account or can it run locally on users machine?